# Function Variable's Value Become Undefined After It Is Returned

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function to find number in 9, 99, 999, 9999... in which the sum of the digit factorials (9! + 9! for 99) of the number is less than the number itself:

```
function findLimit(starting_limit){
    var starting_limit_string = starting_limit.toString();
    var limit_factorial = factorial(9) * starting_limit_string.length;
    if(limit_factorial > starting_limit){
        var new_starting_limit = (starting_limit * 10) + 9;
        findLimit(new_starting_limit);
    } else {
        return starting_limit;
    }
}

var final_limit = findLimit(9);
```

However, final_limit turns out to be undefined. This is despite the fact that, when I set a break point at "return starting_limit", starting_limit is clearly defined as 9999999.

So what's going on here? Why would a defined value change to undefined when returned by my function?

Comment: You aren't returning in the `if`, so the function returns `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `return` on this line:

> ```
> findLimit(new_starting_limit);
> ```

Comment: Wouldn't that just run recursively until the else condition is met?

Comment: @SterlingArcher — It already runs recursively until the else condition is met. This change means that you actually get the value you are looking for back.

Comment: Thank you--I knew it was going to be a silly one, but I had a block while looking for it.